# androidx command not found

Tags: flutter, androidx

I wanted to create a flutter project with androidx enabled by command.
but I founded this. I upgrade flutter but not working

```
$ flutter create --androidx hello_world
Could not find an option named "androidx".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a new project run:

```
flutter create -t <project-type> <new-project-path>
```

Ref:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration